# User Level Access in yii can't run well

Tags: php, yii

I am newbie in yii, I am making an website with yii framework. It is my first time in making USER LEVEL ACCESS. I've created a file **EWebUser.php** in **protected/controllers/**, this is my code `

```
protected function loadUser(){
    if ($this->_model === null){
        $this->_model=  User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
    }
    return $this->_model;
}

function getLevel(){
    $user = $this->loadUser();
    if ($user)
        return $user->status;
    return '';


  }
}
```

then I've also created function namely **accessRules** in **AdminController**. This my code

```
public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('index','delete','btnconf'),
                'expression'=>'$user->getLevel()="supadmin"'

            )
        );
    }
`
```

When I type **`http://localhost/coretankuyii/index.php/admin/index`** in URL while I login with user, admin or even has not login can still access it. My hope someone who can access that URL only someone who has status=supadmin. Do you can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Change the expression to "=="

```
public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('index','delete','btnconf'),
                'expression'=>'$user->getLevel()=="supadmin"'

            )
        );
    }
```

Or if this does not work try the below

```
public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('index','delete','btnconf'),
                'expression'=>array('AdminController','getLevel');

            )
        );
    }

public function getLevel(){
        $user = $this->loadUser();
        if($user->status=='supadmin')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```